# Implementing if-else conditionals with Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have to make a login but for some reason its not working. Could I have some help please?

I've got this code but I can not get it to work.

```
username=input("please enter your username")
password=input("please enter your password")
if username=="student1":
password=="password123"
print("accsess granted")

else username!="student1":
password !="password123"
print "inncorect login"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "its not working"? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Read about [Logical operators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators#logical_operators). Also, your identation is wrong. Indentation is important in python

Comment: Just to add. Don't store passwords as it is. encrypt them (use sha1+salt etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your indentation is off
2. Your `if`s are malformed
3. Your contradictory `print` statements cast doubt on what version you're using (version matters! Parentheses matter!)

---

Lucky for you, the fix is pretty straightforward. You'll need one `if-else` statement. The `else` doesn't need conditions.

```
username = input("please enter your username")
password = input("please enter your password")

if username == "student1" and password == "password123":
    print("access granted")

else:
    print("incorrect login")
```

If you're using python2, please use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: and, access spell is inncorect :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. Still inco**rr**ect :P

Comment: Any other typos from _OP_ I should correct, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

```
if username=="student1" and password=="password123":
  print("accsess granted")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the syntax of if/else wrong. The correct syntax is:

```
if username == "student1" and password == "password123":
   print("access granted")
else:
   print("incorrect login")
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your script checks only if the username is "student1" and performs a useless check on the password. Try this version (assuming Python 2.7):

```
username = raw_input("please enter your username")
password = raw_input("please enter your password")
if username == "student1" and password == "password123":
    print "access granted"
else:
    print "incorrect login"
```

Even better, you should hash your password because right now it's sufficient to open the python file and look around to find the correct password. As an example:

```
from hashlib import md5
username = raw_input("please enter your username")
password = raw_input("please enter your password")
password2 = md5()
password2.update(password)
if username == "student1" and password2.hexdigest() == "482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38":
    print "access granted"
else:
    print "incorrect login"
```

I generated the hash with this code:

```
from hashlib import md5
m = md5()
m.update('password123')
print m.hexdigest()
```

Comment: I appreciate that you went the extra mile with the password but let OP first understand if-else before moving on to cryptography.